# Excel - combine 2 row of value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I achieve the result of pic2 from pic1.

Thank you.

pic1:

[image: pic1]

pic2:

[image: pic2]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't do that with a formula, let me explain:

With a formula, you can take values from cells, do something with those, and put the result in a new cell.

What you want to do, is to change the value of an existing cell into something else, based on another cell, and afterwards clear the value of that other cell. This can't be done with a formula, you need a VBA macro for that, e.g. something like this:

```
Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value + " " + Range("A2").Value
Range("A3").Value = Range("A3").Value + " " + Range("A4").Value
Range("A5").Value = Range("A5").Value + " " + Range("A6").Value
```

Obviously, if it's ok for you to put the results in another column, let's say column C, then it is possible, using following formula (in C1):

```
=A1 & " " & A2
```

A corresponding formula can be entered in cells C3 and C5.

Comment: Can anyone please explain me why the downvote?